# React/ Enzyme - test failing in component that renders content with a map function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have a React project where I have a component that maps throught an array of objects and render other components, like this:

```
return (
    historyParts.map((historyPart, historyPartIndex) =>
      (<div key={`historyPart${historyPartIndex}` // eslint-disable-line react/no-array-index-key
        }
      >
        <div>
          {historyPart.link &&
            <Element>
              <NavLink
                to={createLocationForHistoryItems(handlingLocation, historyPart.link.code)}
              >
                {findLinkText(historyPart[0].link, intl)}
              </NavLink>
            </Element>
            }

          <BubbleText
            bodyText={findText(historyPart.summary)}
            className="bubble-panel__tekst"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      )));
```

This is a test that I wrote for this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallowWithIntl, intlMock } from 'testHelpers/intl-enzyme-test-helper';
import { expect } from 'chai';

import { HistoryDescriptionType9} from './HistorikkMalType9';

const historyPart = {
  cause: null,
  actionPoint: null,
  summary: 'adsadsd',
  link: {
    code: 'UTTAK',
    codeType: 'SKJERMLENKE_TYPE',
    name: 'Uttak',
  },
};
const historyParts = [historyPart , historyPart ];
const handlingLocation = {};

describe('HistoryDescriptionType9', () => {
  it('should render HistoryDescriptionType9', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<HistoryDescriptionType9
      historyParts ={historyParts }
      handlingLocation={handlingLocation}
      intl={intlMock}
    />);

    const bubbleText = wrapper.find('BubbleText');
    expect(bubbleText).to.have.length(historyParts.length);
  });
});
```

So, since I am mapping an array with 2 objects, there should be 2 `BubbleText` components rendered. But, I get a message that the test fails:

```
AssertionError: expected { length: 0 } to have a length of 2 but got 0
      + expected - actual
```

I have also tried with importing the component and using it in find function explicitly, like this:

```
import BubbleText from './bubbleText';

const bubbleText = wrapper.find(BubbleText);
```

But, I got the same error message.
I assume that the test is failing because of the map function. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

idk how your BubbleText component looks like but this issue is maybe because you are passing inside tests `summary: 'adsadsd'` instead of "BubbleText"

Comment: That is not the issue.